# How can I only display certain rows from a database table in ASP?

Tags: sql, database

I have the entire table being pulled in but I want it set up so the only rows that are displayed are the ones with specific information in one column.

Here is my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT [Day], aoc, ryg, reasoning, notes FROM dbo.ryg_conditions ORDER BY aoc ASC,[Day] DESC
```

But I only want to display rows that have "Administration" in the aoc column and then sort those by the date.

I'm new to ASP and databases, please help?

Comment: Can't you add a where-clause to your query? it always best to select just the records you need. Selecting records you don't need is a waste of time and performance :-)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I didn't know about WHERE. Extreme noob here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would usually let the database do the initial restriction

something like this:

```
SELECT [Day], aoc, ryg, reasoning, notes 
FROM dbo.ryg_conditions 
WHERE aoc ='Administration'
ORDER BY aoc ASC,[Day] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into `WHERE`

In your case, you would add to your query:

```
SELECT [Day], aoc, ryg, reasoning, notes 
FROM dbo.ryg_conditions 
WHERE aoc = 'Administration'
ORDER BY aoc ASC,[Day] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a WHERE statement.

```
SELECT [Day], aoc, ryg, reasoning, notes 
FROM dbo.ryg_conditions 
WHERE aoc = 'Administration'
ORDER BY aoc ASC,[Day] DESC
```